# SQL : select a comparison ? eg, a boolean result?

Tags: sql

I was wondering if something like this was possible in SQL :

```
select (
  (select count(*) from T) = (select count(*) from T t where t.something = thing)
)
```

This is probably very far from the actual SQL if it is possible, I don't write database requests so often.

How could I get the result of my comparison with a single request ? Basically, if I had no time, I would just make two requests and compare the results in Java (boooooo !! I know).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This should be valid for any DBMS that supports "real" boolean types.

Comment: Are you allowed to use store procs? Then it is really simple. Save it in two different variables and return the result of comparision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your query should work, the following is probably faster because only a single query is needed

```
select total_count = thing_count
from (
   select count(*) as total_count,
          sum(case when something = 42 then 1 end) as thing_count
   from t
) t
```

The above is ANSI SQL and should work in any DBMS supporting a real boolean type. In Oracle you would need to use an expression in the outer select:

```
select case when total_count = thing_count then 1 else 0 end
from (
   select count(*) as total_count,
          sum(case when something = 42 then 1 end) as thing_count
   from t
) t
```

Comment: Still seems a strange approach to find out if there is something that differs from 42 IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your query like this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (select count(*) from T) = (select count(*) from T t where t.something = thing) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

However, if the first `T` is the same as the second `T` then what you actually want to check is if there are any records where `t.something <> thing` .. right ?

In that case you could simply do :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (select * from T t where t.something != thing) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```